# How can I properly dynamically allocate memory for an "array" of strings

Tags: c++, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, I'm just messing around with some code that asks the user how much personnel they'd like to hire. After entering the number they'd like, I initiate 3 pointers. The pointer I'm focused on is the string pointer "employee_Names". After initialization, I try and dynamically allocate the proper amount of memory required based on the user input to the pointer "employee_Names".

I think my syntax is good for that part, but my problems come when I try to actually store information in the memory allocated. As seen in the code, I try to directly set employee_Names[0] equal to a name, but that gives me errors.

```
personnel = requested_service() - 1;

string  *employee_Names;
int *employee_Ages;
char *employee_Company;

employee_Names = (string*)malloc(personnel);

employee_Names[0] = "Bahn";

printf("Employee number 1 is: %s", employee_Names[0]);
```

I would really love some enlightenment. Let me know if I need to be more specific in an area, or if more code needs to be seen.

Comment: In C++, "dynamic array of strings" is spelled `std::vector<std::string>`. Though in your example, you likely want to define  a class `Employee`, and then use `std::vector<Employee>`

Comment: `std::string` is a complex object that requires proper construction. `malloc` provides memory but does not call constructors. Without one of `string`s constructor being invoked, you don't really have a `string`. You have a block of memory pretending to be a `string` and it's pretty much a time bomb. Doing just about anything `string`ish with this uninitialized memory will cause the program to break, and the program crashing is the best case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used `malloc()`. You allocate memory for `personnel` number of *bytes*, not number of *strings*. And you don't construct any `string` objects in that memory at all.

Don't use `malloc()` in C++ at all, if you can avoid it. Use `new` and `new[]` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

personnel = ...;

std::string *employee_Names;
...

employee_Names = new std::string[personnel];
employee_Names[0] = "Bahn";
...

std::printf("Employee number 1 is: %s", employee_Names[0].c_str());

...

delete[] employee_Names;
```

That said, you really should use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` directly. Also, use `std::cout` instead of `printf()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

personnel = ...;

std::vector<std::string> employee_Names(personnel);
...

employee_Names[0] = "Bahn";
...

std::cout << "Employee number 1 is: " << employee_Names[0];
```

Lastly, given your variable names, consider using a `class` or `struct` to group an employee's details together:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Employee
{
    std::string Name;
    int Age;
    char Company;
};

...

personnel = ...;

std::vector<Employee> employees(personnel);

employees[0].Name = "Bahn";
...

std::cout << "Employee number 1 is: " << employees[0].Name;
```